# How to resolve the HiveServer2Error Error that occurs while connecting to Impala DB

Tags: jupyter, impala

I am doing Data comparison Testing between Oracle DB & Impala DB. Before that we need to connect to Impala DB. Impala Db contains Record Sets. I need to fetch those records for comparing with Oracle DB contents which also contains the same records. Her is the Code for Connecting to Impala DB.

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle``
from impala.util import as_pandas
import os
import pandas
from impala.dbapi import connect
```

#impala

```
IMPALA_HOST = os.getenv('IMPALA_HOST', 'dubuedgdh06q.quintiles.net')
impconn = connect(host='dubuedgdh06q.quintiles.net',
port=21050,
use_ssl=True,
database='edgeuistd_bkp',
user='q1065246',
kerberos_service_name='impala',
auth_mechanism = 'NOSASL')
impcursor = impconn.cursor()
#impcursor.execute('select * from unmask1_prod_3385_crf_futdr')


But the following Error message is displayed upon execution in Jupyter Notebook.


HiveServer2Error                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8e5a9ca22e88> in <module>
     54 auth_mechanism = 'NOSASL')
     55 # Execute using SQL
---> 56 impcursor = impconn.cursor()
     57 #impcursor.execute('select * from unmask1_prod_3385_crf_futdr')
     58 

~\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py in cursor(self, user, configuration, 
convert_types, dictify, fetch_error)
    122         log.debug('.cursor(): getting new session_handle')
    123 
--> 124         session = self.service.open_session(user, configuration)
    125 
    126         log.debug('HiveServer2Cursor(service=%s, session_handle=%s, '

~\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py in open_session(self, user, configuration)
   1073                               username=user,
   1074                               configuration=configuration)
-> 1075         resp = self._rpc('OpenSession', req)
   1076         return HS2Session(self, resp.sessionHandle,
   1077                           resp.configuration,
```

~\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py in _rpc(self, func_name, request)
991     def _rpc(self, func_name, request):
992         self._log_request(func_name, request)
--> 993         response = self._execute(func_name, request)
994         self._log_response(func_name, response)
995         err_if_rpc_not_ok(response)

```
~\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py in _execute(self, func_name, request)
   1021             tries_left -= 1
   1022 
-> 1023         raise HiveServer2Error('Failed after retrying {0} times'
   1024                                .format(self.retries))
   1025 

    HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times

    Can you help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks,
Mallikarjun
```